# Proving the limits of two sequences of real numbers are equal

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $(x_{n})$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $x_{n}>0 \; \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $, and let

$$ y_{n} =\frac{n}{\frac{1}{x_{1}} + \frac{1}{x_{2}}+...+\frac{1}{x_{n}}}, \; n\in \mathbb{N}. $$
I  would like to prove :

1. If $(x_{n})$ is a convergent sequence, then  $\lim y_{n}=\lim x_{n}$.
2. If $\lim x_{n}=+\infty $, then $\lim y_{n}=+ \infty$.

I tried applying the Stolz-Cesàro theorem on $\frac{1}{y_{n}}$ and got $\lim \frac{1}{x_{n+1}}=\lim \frac{1}{y_{n}}$, (implying that since $(x_{n})$ converges, $\lim \frac{1}{y_{n}}=\frac{1}{x}$, where $x=\lim x_{n}$), but I don't know where to go from here (nor am I confident that my choice to apply the Stolz-Cesàro theorem was the right one in the first place).

Comment: (you do need to be careful with the case that $x_n\rightarrow0$)

Comment: @charlestoncrabb but $x_{n}>0 \; \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$... is that case problematic regardless?

Comment: Not really problematic, just needs to be addressed. You may certainly have a positive sequence that converges to zero: $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$, e.g..